# Issue with code that takes in 2 positive numbers and prints every prime number in between? - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, func

I am trying to write a function that takes in 2 positive integers and prints every prime number in between them, and also including the 2 numbers as well if they are prime.  This is what I have currently, but it will just print the first number is prime and the rest are not.  I have looked this up online and I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with this code, as many other sites use similar logic.

```
func printPrimes(from firstNum: Int, to lastNum: Int) {
    var newFirstNum = firstNum
    if firstNum == 0 {
        newFirstNum = 2
    }


    let numbers = newFirstNum...lastNum


    // Goes through each number from 2-100 starting from 2.
    for number in numbers {

        var primeValue = false
        let startPoint = 2

        let number2 = startPoint...number

        // Takes current number and divides by every number from 2 to the given number.
        for currentIndex in number2 {
            primeValue = false
            if number % currentIndex != 0 {
                primeValue = true
            }
        }
            if primeValue == false {
                print("\(number) is not prime")

            } else {
                print("\(number) is prime")
            } 
    } 
}
```

This is the type of function call I am using:

```
printPrimes(from: 0, to: 100)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues. Mainly your setting of `primeValue` is all wrong. You first set it to false. Then you reset it to false for every factor you are about to try, even if you've already determined the number is prime.

It would be better to assume the number is prime until finding a factor. And you need to avoid checking a number against itself.

Here is your fixed code:

```
func printPrimes(from firstNum: Int, to lastNum: Int) {
    var newFirstNum = firstNum
    if firstNum == 0 {
        newFirstNum = 2
    }

    let numbers = newFirstNum...lastNum

    // Goes through each number from 2-100 starting from 2.
    for number in numbers {
        var primeValue = true // assume prime unless we find a factor
        let startPoint = 2

        let number2 = startPoint..<number // Don't include number

        // Takes current number and divides by every number from 2 to the given number.
        for currentIndex in number2 {
            if number % currentIndex == 0 {
                primeValue = false // we found a factor, not prime
                break // no need to check for any other factors
            }
        }

        if primeValue {
            print("\(number) is prime")
        } else {
            print("\(number) is not prime")
        }
    }
}

printPrimes(from: 0, to: 100)
```